# Why (non existing) subdomain of my add-on domain redirecting to primary domain?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, server, subdomain, plesk

I am using 1and1 cloud with plesk.

I have a http://primary.com and an http://addon.com

Right now if if some one enter any none existing subdomain e.g. blabla.addon.com, the URL in browser address bar stays the same but contents coming from http://primary.com/

I wanted contents to come from http://addon.com

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: What web server are you using?  What have you tried?  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe your have a Wildcard DNS record *.primary.com and *addon.com and your primary.com virtual host is configured as default one. So all requests that are not link do any other Virtual Host goes to this default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because by default Plesk will serve it's "Web Server's Default Page" template.

If you want to change this behaviour you need to set a default domain that will be served instead.

The setting you are looking for is located at:

Tools & Settings > IP Addresses > Your IP (click) > Default site > Domain (addon.com)